# Method Not Found On Java Static Class

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I am using the Android Universal Image Loader.

In all the sample code, the views are created via XML. I need to create my views via Java (no inflating). I am trying to cast the View view as a PhotoDisplayView object instead and call .test(). But .test() cannot be found.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = new PhotoDisplayView(parent.getContext());
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                holder.imageView = (PhotoDisplayView)view.test();//test() CANNOT BE FOUND
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
}
```

Here is my static class

```
static class PhotoDisplayView extends FrameLayout
    {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public PhotoDisplayView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
        }

        public void test()
        {
            Log.d("TEST","TEST");
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why casting it as a PhotoDisplayView object wont give me access to its functions? Im taking a view object and casting it as a subclassed version of it. Why can't it find the method?

Note: If I declare the object as a PhotoDisplayView instead of a View I do have access to the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this just needs some more parentheses to make sure you're doing things in the right order. `(PhotoDisplayView)view.test();` would be interpreted as "Call `View.test()` and then cast the results to `PhotoDisplayView`. Instead, try this:

```
// Should work
holder.imageView = ((PhotoDisplayView)view).test();
```

**Edit:**
Well, the other problem is that your `test()` method is type `void`. If you want to assign it to `holder.imageView`, you need to make sure that it has a return value.

Comment: Ya I didn't need to get the method working just find it haha.

Comment: @Aggressor It might look that way at first. But the way you had it the compiler was basically doing: 1. Call `test()` on a `View` object. 2. Cast the result to `PhotoDisplayView` . Because `View` doesn't have a `test()` method, it errored out at step 1. Adding the parentheses makes it cast the class first, *then* run the method.

Comment: So I was casting the result. Gotcha, this clears it up. Coming from C#, Obj-C, and Swift, I'm having a real hay day with with Java hahaha

Answer (score -2):

i think you cast to PhotoDisplayView but you save this object as ViewHolder not as PhotoDisplayView.

You can do it:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new PhotoDisplayView(parent.getContext());
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;
            PhotoDisplayView photodisplay=view.test();
            photodisplay.photodisplaymethods();
            holder.imageView = photodisplay;
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
```

}